# Should I bottle whole batch after fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, priming

I read that after fermentation finishes, there is no harm in waiting before priming.

I am using kits, and wort is 4 gallons. Can I bottle 1 gallon of beer, and leave the remaining gallons in fermenter to bottle next week? From what I understand from guides, it seems once I open the fermenter I should bottle all.

I don't have enough bottles, or lets say I don't want to fill my home with bottles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bottle up some and leave the rest it should be fine. I have done this before and it was fine. I usually add a spoonful of sugar to the FV to ensure it generates a bit more CO2 to 'blanket' it after drawing out the volume into bottles.

Answer (score 2):

While I can see the benefit of doing this from time to time, I would not recommend it in general practice. Every time you handle the beer, you risk introducing oxygen. Every time you open the fermenter, you risk infection. 
You can avoid bottle build up by using bigger bottles or kegging.